# Approving items in a folder

Tags: folder

I was wondering if there's a good way of creating a procedure which goes like this:

Select users upload documents that require approval onto a folder. Once in that folder, if they are not approved then a workflow begins.

Really, I wanted to create a custom document set in which files that are uploaded to a certain folder are labeled as "Not Approved."

Comment: Are you opposed to using columns and fields with views? Are you trying to keep the folder paradigm so that users feel more like they're in a traditional file share?

Comment: I do not oppose using columns and fields.

In fact, I was in the process of creating something in which I use a column with the field "Approved?" which is a simple yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has out-of-the-box content approval features.

Check out [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a-library-HA010154436.aspx).    If you complete Steps 1 and 2, you should be able to either:

1. Create 1 view that groups the documents on the *Approval Status*
   column (it will be added once you complete Steps 1 and 2 above.
2. Create 2 seperate views that both filter on the *Approval Status* column's different values (Pending, Approved, Rejected).

[Here's](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-or-change-a-view-HA010021577.aspx#BM3) an article that describes more on creating views.

Finally, you could add web parts for the list that use the new views to display the library's content to the users.